# SP2010 Update Site Title and Description - Security problem

Tags: development, application-pages, spweb

I've created a custom application page to update the Title and Description of a site.
The page is generating an access denied and the following error message in the log file:

> Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070005

```
 using (SPSite SiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb UpdateCurrentweb = SiteCollection.RootWeb)
            {
                    UpdateCurrentweb.Title = SiteTitle.Text.ToString();
                    UpdateCurrentweb.Description = SiteDescription.Text.ToString();
                    UpdateCurrentweb.Update();}}
```

Adding:

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { });`

or

```
UpdateCurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
UpdateCurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

Is NOT resolving the problem.

Comment: Hi, why don't you use default /_layouts/prjsetng.aspx page ?

Comment: I assume that the SiteCol variable in the second using statement should be "SiteCollection" right? Otherwise you would be breaking elevation by using an instance that has been created outside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges privileges. Can you please confirm that?

Comment: SPArchaeologist: correct that was a typo

Comment: Alexander, my page is doing more than just adjusting title and description but only fails on this particular part of code... And needs to be run by a non site collection admin!

Comment: Yes, that would have been too simple...just wanted to sort the "used one variable while meaning to use another" error out, to be sure. That said... [are you working on an FBA web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684128/access-denied-when-trying-to-read-information-about-sharepoint-groups)?

Comment: Where are you placing the SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()?  It needs to be outside of the Using statements, not merely around the three key lines of code.

Comment: Dave, this was my problem. After putting the SPSecrurity statements outside of my using clause it went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the initial question was the location of the SPSecurity clause. After putting it outside the using statements it worked fine! The purpose was to update the Root Web but the remark of James is very valid as well! –

Answer (score 1):

Do you realise that that code statement will update the Root Web of the site collection, no matter what level of website you're in. Think you might want to try `SiteCollection.OpenWeb()` in your second using statement, instead of `SiteCollection.RootWeb`. This will let you set the title and description of the current website in question (unless it's your intention to do otherwise).

Comment: The solution for the initial question was the location of the SPSecurity clause. After putting it outside the using statements it worked fine! The purpose was to update the Root Web but the remark of James is very valid as well!

Comment: Also, don't dispose RootWeb, think I saw a discussion on this somewhere else on this site recently (will be on the first couple of pages somewhere)...